# Dodged bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a dodged barchart with different cell cycles for each cell type within each condition.

**dput(DF_count)**

```
structure(list(orig.ident = c("treated", "treated", "treated", 
"treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", 
"treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", 
"treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", 
"treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", 
"treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
"untreated", "untreated", "untreated"), Phase = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("G1", "G2M", "S"), class = "factor"), old.ident = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("Fibroblast", "T cell", "Macrophage", 
"Stellate", "Acinar", "Endothelial", "Tumor", "B cell", "Mast cell", 
"Ductal", "Islets of Langerhans"), class = "factor"), n = c(3257L, 
666L, 560L, 446L, 91L, 464L, 192L, 506L, 162L, 207L, 90L, 603L, 
608L, 238L, 98L, 22L, 110L, 215L, 95L, 63L, 97L, 10L, 2191L, 
618L, 335L, 349L, 35L, 294L, 250L, 231L, 142L, 153L, 16L, 2910L, 
1259L, 853L, 559L, 1134L, 348L, 306L, 133L, 116L, 12L, 192L, 
706L, 1186L, 374L, 112L, 616L, 106L, 277L, 32L, 47L, 6L, 27L, 
1715L, 1312L, 575L, 390L, 1036L, 250L, 252L, 91L, 66L, 8L, 68L
), Freq = c(53.8258139150554, 35.2008456659619, 49.4263018534863, 
49.9440089585666, 61.4864864864865, 53.4562211981567, 29.2237442922374, 
60.8173076923077, 44.141689373297, 45.2954048140044, 77.5862068965517, 
9.96529499256321, 32.1353065539112, 21.0061782877317, 10.9742441209406, 
14.8648648648649, 12.6728110599078, 32.7245053272451, 11.4182692307692, 
17.1662125340599, 21.2253829321663, 8.62068965517241, 36.2088910923814, 
32.6638477801269, 29.567519858782, 39.0817469204927, 23.6486486486486, 
33.8709677419355, 38.0517503805175, 27.7644230769231, 38.6920980926431, 
33.4792122538293, 13.7931034482759, 54.5863815419246, 33.5107798775619, 
47.3362930077692, 52.6861451460886, 40.7035175879397, 49.4318181818182, 
36.6467065868263, 51.953125, 50.6550218340611, 46.1538461538462, 
66.8989547038328, 13.2432939410992, 31.5677402182592, 20.7547169811321, 
10.5560791705938, 22.1105527638191, 15.0568181818182, 33.1736526946108, 
12.5, 20.5240174672489, 23.0769230769231, 9.40766550522648, 32.1703245169762, 
34.9214799041789, 31.9089900110988, 36.7577756833176, 37.1859296482412, 
35.5113636363636, 30.1796407185629, 35.546875, 28.82096069869, 
30.7692307692308, 23.6933797909408)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -66L), groups = structure(list(
    orig.ident = c("treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", 
    "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", "treated", 
    "treated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
    "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", "untreated", 
    "untreated", "untreated"), old.ident = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L), .Label = c("Fibroblast", "T cell", 
    "Macrophage", "Stellate", "Acinar", "Endothelial", "Tumor", 
    "B cell", "Mast cell", "Ductal", "Islets of Langerhans"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = list(c(1L, 12L, 23L), c(2L, 13L, 24L), c(3L, 14L, 
    25L), c(4L, 15L, 26L), c(5L, 16L, 27L), c(6L, 17L, 28L), 
        c(7L, 18L, 29L), c(8L, 19L, 30L), c(9L, 20L, 31L), c(10L, 
        21L, 32L), c(11L, 22L, 33L), c(34L, 45L, 56L), c(35L, 
        46L, 57L), c(36L, 47L, 58L), c(37L, 48L, 59L), c(38L, 
        49L, 60L), c(39L, 50L, 61L), c(40L, 51L, 62L), c(41L, 
        52L, 63L), c(42L, 53L, 64L), c(43L, 54L, 65L), c(44L, 
        55L, 66L))), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Used this code to generate a stacked bar graph:

```
ggplot(DF_Count, aes(x = old.ident, y = Freq, fill = Phase))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(Freq, 2),"%")),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~orig.ident)
```

But want the 2 conditions to be next to each other on the same graph. How do I use this dataset and create a dodged bar chart to have both conditions together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather straight-forward work-around for your problem:

```
ggplot(DF_Count, aes(x = orig.ident, y = Freq, fill = Phase))+
  geom_col()+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(Freq, 2),"%")),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  facet_wrap(~old.ident)
```

[image]

It does not give a single plot or a dodged bar chart representing the two conditions you would like to visualize. For an exact solution to your problem, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597859/7236472) (actually the answer below the linked answer is analogous to what I have suggested above).